# Tensorflow takes long time to connect to Nvidia-Drivers

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I have installed my Nvidia-drivers on my remote-server and

`$nvidia-smi` also returns the list of devices

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.48                 Driver Version: 410.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 36%   64C    P2    78W / 300W |   9813MiB / 10989MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   45C    P8     8W / 300W |    774MiB / 10989MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       333      C   python                                      9039MiB |
|    0     11773      C   python                                       191MiB |
|    0     12111      C   python                                       191MiB |
|    0     12591      C   python                                       191MiB |
|    0     12999      C   python                                       191MiB |
|    1     11773      C   python                                       191MiB |
|    1     12111      C   python                                       191MiB |
|    1     12591      C   python                                       191MiB |
|    1     12999      C   python                                       191MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when I try to use.

```
>>> from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
>>> device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

It is taking too long time to give the list of devices

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
>>> device_lib.list_local_devices()
2019-09-05 15:56:27.568310: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-09-05 15:56:27.596133: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3600000000 Hz
2019-09-05 15:56:27.597408: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55da9a2fe370 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-09-05 15:56:27.597421: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-09-05 15:56:27.598606: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2019-09-05 15:59:27.755714: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-05 15:59:27.757588: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-05 15:59:27.758287: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55da9c6d9140 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-09-05 15:59:27.758299: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-09-05 15:59:27.758303: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (1): GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, Compute Capability 7.5
2019-09-05 15:59:27.758508: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-05 15:59:27.758883: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.755
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2019-09-05 15:59:27.758919: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-05 15:59:27.759313: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 1 with properties:
name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.755
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0
2019-09-05 15:59:27.759441: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-09-05 15:59:27.760153: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-09-05 15:59:27.760803: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2019-09-05 15:59:27.760941: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2019-09-05 15:59:27.761755: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2019-09-05 15:59:27.762395: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2019-09-05 15:59:27.764370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-09-05 15:59:27.764435: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-05 15:59:27.764846: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-05 15:59:27.765262: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-05 15:59:27.765638: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-05 15:59:27.766026: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2019-09-05 15:59:27.766046: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-09-05 15:59:27.767185: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-09-05 15:59:27.767194: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 1
2019-09-05 15:59:27.767197: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N Y
2019-09-05 15:59:27.767200: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 1:   Y N
2019-09-05 15:59:27.767370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-05 15:59:27.767755: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-05 15:59:27.768175: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-05 15:59:27.768546: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 950 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2019-09-05 15:59:27.768811: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-09-05 15:59:27.769219: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:1 with 9703 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 14451063918691325445
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 3472161188084064797
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 1975372846861552523
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:1"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 8192574289833793917
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 996802560
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
    link {
      device_id: 1
      type: "StreamExecutor"
      strength: 1
    }
  }
}
incarnation: 9560317274260358344
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5"
, name: "/device:GPU:1"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 10175270093
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
    link {
      type: "StreamExecutor"
      strength: 1
    }
  }
}
incarnation: 16877706551631715197
physical_device_desc: "device: 1, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 7.5"
```

and when I try to check the info to use nvidia-docker

```
sudo nvidia-container-cli -k -d /dev/tty info
```

it gives the following output:

```
I0905 09:00:43.600569 9993 driver.c:233] driver service terminated with signal 15
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: driver error: timed out
```

Comment: The nvidia-persistenced service should be running to keep the nvidia-driver loaded at all times. For information on how to enable it see: https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/driver-persistence/index.html, or the NVIDIA driver doc for your operating system.

Comment: I have a same issue. Could you solve it?

Comment: check if the devices are up as in nvlink is up and working. mostly it must be the dust that creates the issue

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is an issue with my nvlink,

so if Incase if your training is taking too much Time to start.

Please check if the links are up and not down.

The following command is as follows.

```
$ nvidia-smi nvlink --status

GPU 0: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti (UUID: GPU-797d7153-ea28-d678-dc38-859b914d6dd7)
     Link 0: 25.781 GB/s
     Link 1: 25.781 GB/s
GPU 1: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti (UUID: GPU-8807c553-7571-582d-c2ee-02993527b0a6)
     Link 0: 25.781 GB/s
     Link 1: 25.781 GB/s
```

Thanks